# Screen Time App stats for Windows 10 PC (not mobile)

Tags: windows

I know [Microsoft Family Groups](https://www.howtogeek.com/672890/how-to-limit-screen-time-on-windows-10) allows user set limit screen time.

But I don't want to lock down anyone's account. I'd just like to get stats.

Does Windows 10 have an app similar to [Screen Time](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982) on iOS/[Android](https://www.macworld.com/article/3295880/android-digital-wellbeing-vs-ios-screen-time.html) that produces stats about which apps have been used and how long have they been used on a daily basis?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Family Groups also allows to monitor the screen time of family members.

This is done by using *Activity Reporting*.
To enable, click the *check recent activity* link from the Your family page.
Toggle on *Activity reporting* and check the box *Email weekly reports to me*.

[image]

On the same recent activity page, you can see web browsing activities, apps, and games used and screen time usage. You can also block apps that you don’t want your child using.

[image]

For more information, see the article
[Manage Your Kid’s Screen Time and Track Online Activity in Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/manage-kids-screen-time-track-online-activity-windows-10/).

Comment: Thank you! Does the page come from Windows Desktop or the website (https://account.microsoft.com/family) ?

Comment: In *Settings > Accounts > Family & other people*, click "Manage family settings online". Or directly from [here](https://account.microsoft.com/account/manage-my-account).