# change availability of installed program for other users in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, user-accounts, administrator

I installed some programs as admin(the only user created at that time). Later I created one more standard non-admin user. Now these programs are by default available for later user also.
I want to make some of the programs completely unavailable for this later user such that user doesn't even know about the program is actually installed or not.
I don't want re-install these programs.
If this is not possible then please suggest a way that this user need to enter admin credentials before running those programs.

Comment: So you are trying to prevent applications from being ran by specific users?  This is normally handled through a group policy

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft account?

Comment: yes i am logged in with Microsoft account.

Comment: @ramhound could u explain how to do this by group policy.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Family Groups also allows to monitor and control the activities
of family members. If you define the other users using this mechanism,
you would have total control over their actions.

For more information, see the
[the Microsoft Family Groups website](https://account.microsoft.com/family/?refd=www.howtogeek.com).

The post
[Screen Time App stats for Windows 10 PC (not mobile)](https://superuser.com/questions/1628272/screen-time-app-stats-for-windows-10-pc-not-mobile)
will also be helpful.